# How to cache unlimited number of static pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a Rails app which allows users to create unlimited number of static pages (I store these pages in postgres database), because these pages are statics I would like to use page caching, but I am not sure what's the limit number/size of caching pages in Rails, can I cache unlimited number of pages ?

Comment: You totally can, if you have unlimited amount of resources.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to cache everything, you might as well cache nothing. Performance will be the same. You cache data because it's hot, not because it's static.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev those pages are stored in database, will that make any difference ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't make any difference. To cache all those pages, you need X gigs of RAM. Just add that amount of RAM to the DB server, so that it doesn't have to page data out to disk.

Answer (score 1):

we do this on our main company blog at https://reinteractive.net.

What you probably want to do is do fragment caching on the show action of the page you want to cache. There are some pitfalls to this, the biggest of which is expiring the cache if the underlying page changes.

It works like this:

In the `routes.rb` file:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  get "page/:id" => "pages#show"
end
```

In the controller (`app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController::Base
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Note here in the controller you are hitting the database on every request but this should be a really fast request with the correct index in place.

Then in the view (`app/views/pages/show.html.erb`):

```
<% cache("pages/show/#{@page.id}-#{@page.updated_at.to_i}") do %>
  <%# Render your complex page here %>
<% end %>
```

What you gain from caching a fragment like this is that the output of the rendering gets stored in the cache and if this page takes a while to render, you can get significant time savings, especially if it takes 100ms or more to render the page and all it's parts, you pay for it the first time, and then after that it loads in a few milliseconds.

Note we are checking the last update time of the page?  This is so that if you want to expire this cache (and render again) all you need to do is call `page.touch` on the page object to update is `updated_at` time.

If you have any other objects that could also update (such as say a `page.header_image` or something, then you can also put the updated_at on these related objects into the cache key as well, or expire them manually when you update the page.

An alternative to adding `updated_at` into the cache key is expiring them in the model like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :expire_cache
  def expire_cache
    Rails.cache.delete("CACHE_KEY")
  end
end
```

But this has it's own challenges.

Good luck!

Comment: He has static pages. No complicated rendering. In fact, no rendering whatsoever, if I understand correctly. Just fetch from the database and stream directly to the client.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How that no rendering ? the pages are created by users and stored in database, then I render that page in the view something like this `<%= @page.html_source %>` my Idea here is : if I cache those pages I will maybe decrease the time of hitting the database each time a user see a page

Comment: @medBo: it's not worth it to cache a page which will be accessed once a month. You better give this RAM to database server. If data is in memory, most databases can deliver throughput in the same order of magnitude as memcached (when records are accessed by primary key, or query is otherwise trivial)

Comment: Oh, and also, blind performance tuning is (almost) always unrewarding. To fix the slow parts, you have to identify them. Which means profiling your app and actually measuring things. You'll likely to find out that, for example, the database is very fast, but your app is dog-slow, because you have a N+1 query in there somewhere. (just an example)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I got your point here, but those page are not accessed only once a month, some of my users have hundreds of thousands of followers, so they bring a huge traffic to their pages! do you still thinking I don't need to do caching ?

Comment: @medBo: you need to cache only those few hot pages, not _all_ of them. That was my point.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How I can do that ? it's very hard to do, because I have a wysiwyg page creator and it's not me who create every page... pages are created dynamically by users I have no control over that

Comment: @medBo: well, caching (done properly) is a hard problem. It is, in fact, one of the only two hard problems in computering: cache invalidation and naming things.

Comment: @medBo: You could cache all pages, but with a short TTL. So that rarely accessed pages will soon be evicted, but the hot pages will stay in the cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84724/discussion-between-medbo-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you help me with a subject on codementor ?

Comment: I think so, yeah. Posted a link to the chat. :)

Answer (score 1):

@MikelLindsaar 's answer is good but kinda too much work for something that could be handled easier, ActiveRecord objects have a method called `cache_key` that auto generates a unique key for each record, if the record gets touched or updated, the generated key will be different, this key is used for generating the whole view caching key, which is a function that has a lot of parameters, like the object id, updated_at *(from the `cache_key`)*, and the view's hash *( the cache gets invalidated if the view file is updated, not just the db)*, so there's no worry about any stale data, all you need to do would be:

**The controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController::Base
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**The view**

```
<% cache @page do %>
  <%# Render your page here %>
<% end %>
```

if you have multiple pages that use the same page object you could use a compound cache key, something like this for example

```
<% cache(prefix: 'page/show', page: @page) %>
```

and rails will handle the generation of the caching key.

More info about this over here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Comment: my problem is not about how to cache a page but about if it's possible to cache an unlimited number of pages, because these pages are created by users and I don't know how many page they will create... so I am worry that there is a limitation when it comes to do caching

Comment: check the different cache stores from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores, you can configure caches to use files or memory or redis, what ever suits you best.

Comment: @MohammaAbuShady thank you man :) ... I sent u an email at your stackoverflow address